# Having problems getting info from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm receiving this error:

```
 Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\dev\includes\class\class_db_mysql.php on line 67
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0030  343136  {main}( )   ..\edit.php:0
2   0.0103  437760  database->fetch_row( )  ..\edit.php:380
3   0.0103  437808  mysql_fetch_assoc ( )   ..\class_db_mysql.php:67
```

page code is:

```
 <?php
    require_once 'includes/header.php';
$_GET['edit'] = abs((int) $_GET['edit']);
function item_dropdown1($connection,$ddname="item1",$selected=-1)
{
    global $db;
    $ret="<select name='$ddname' type='dropdown'>";
    $q=$db->query("SELECT * FROM stock ORDER BY name ASC");
if($selected < 1) { $ret.="<option value='0' selected='selected'>-- None --</option>"; }
else { $ret.="<option value='0'>-- None --</option>"; }
    while($r1=$db->fetch_row($q))
        {
            $ret.="\n<option value='{$r1['id']}'";
if ($selected == $r1['id']) { $ret.=" selected='selected'";$first=1; } 
            $ret.=">{$r1['name']} For {$r1['cat']} &gt; {$r1['subcat']}</option>";
        }
$ret.="\n</select>";
return $ret;
}
$q1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE r_id={$_GET['edit']}");
$selnotes=$db->query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE linkedtoid={$_GET['edit']}");
$selparts=$db->query("SELECT * FROM usedparts WHERE binded_to={$_GET['edit']}");


$fq=$db->fetch_row($q1);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['first_name']));
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['last_name']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$cno = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['contact_no']));
$fault = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['fault']));
$make = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['make']));
$device = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['device']));
$model = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['model']));
$price = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['price']));
$notes = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['notes']));
$status = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['status']));
$posted = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['posted']));
$partsfitted = $_POST['pf'];
if (isset($_POST['posted']) == 'TRUE') {
$db->query("UPDATE repairs SET r_oem='$make', r_device='$device', r_mod='$model', r_reserve='$fault', r_price='$price', r_notes='$notes', rc_fname='$fname', rc_lname='$lname', rc_email='$email', rc_contactno='$cno', rc_status='$status' WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}'");
if ($partsfitted == 1) {
    $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET rc_status=3 WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}'");
    if ($fq['part1id']) {
    $item1=$fq['part1id'];
    $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited-1, totalused=totalused+1 WHERE id='$item1'");
    $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part1id=0 WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}' ");
    }
    if ($fq['part2id']) {
    $item2=$fq['part2id'];
    $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited-1, totalused=totalused+1 WHERE id='$item2'");
    $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part2id=0 WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}' ");
    }
    if ($fq['part3id']) {
    $item3=$fq['part1id'];
    $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited-1, totalused=totalused+1 WHERE id='$item3'");
    $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part3id=0 WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}' ");
    }
    if ($fq['part4id']) {
    $item4=$fq['part1id'];
    $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited-1, totalused=totalused+1 WHERE id='$item4'");
    $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part4id=0 WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}' ");
    }
    if ($fq['part5id']) {
    $item5=$fq['part1id'];
    $db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited-1, totalused=totalused+1 WHERE id='$item5'");
    $db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part5id=0 WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}' ");
    }
    else {print "This item has already been marked as repaired";}
}

echo '<font color="green">OK</font> : Successfully UPDATED ID'; PRINT " {$_GET['edit']}  <b>";
echo '</b><br />';
}

if(!$_GET['edit'])
{

// no profile defined. give list of last 100 entries in table..
print  "Click a listing below to edit it.";
$qresults=$db->query("SELECT * FROM repairs order by r_id DESC LIMIT 100");
print "<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" width=\"80%\"><tr style='background:lightblue'><th colspan=\"6\"><h3>Last 100 entries in descending order.</h3></th></tr>";
echo '<tr class="bgalt5"><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone No</th><th>Device</th><th>status</th><th>Edit / Delete</th></tr>';
while($qr=$db->fetch_row($qresults))
{
if ($alternate % 2 == 0){
echo "<tr class='bgalt1'>";
}
else{
echo "<tr class='bgalt3'>";
}
print "
<td>{$qr['rc_fname']}</td>
<td>{$qr['rc_lname']}</td>
<td>{$qr['rc_contactno']}</td>
<td>{$qr['r_oem']} > {$qr['r_device']} > {$qr['r_mod']}</td>
<td>";
if ($qr['rc_status'] == 1) {echo 'Received';}
else if ($qr['rc_status'] == 2) {echo 'Part Waiting';}
else if ($qr['rc_status'] == 3) {echo 'Complete';}
else if ($qr['rc_status'] == 4) {echo 'Beyond Repair';}
else if ($qr['rc_status'] == 5) {echo 'In Progress';}
else {echo 'Error: Status value is not a expected / possible value.';}
print"</td><td><a href=\"edit.php?edit={$qr['r_id']}\"><font color=\"green\">Edit</font></a> | <a href=\"delete.php?del={$qr['r_id']}\"><font color=\"red\">X</font></a></tr>";
$alternate++;
}
print "<table>";
}
else
{
if($db->num_rows($q1) == 0)
{
print "Sorry, we could not find a repair with that ID, check your source.";
}
if($db->num_rows($q1) == 1)
{
print "<fieldset>
<script>
function ins_apple(){
    var text = \"Apple\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function ins_microsoft(){
    var text = \"Microsoft\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function isn_hp(){
    var text = \"HP\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function ins_dell(){
    var text = \"Dell\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function ins_samsung(){
    var text = \"Samsung\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function ins_toshiba(){
    var text = \"Toshiba\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function ins_asus(){
    var text = \"Asus\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function ins_lenovo(){
    var text = \"Lenovo\";
        document.forms.edit.make.value = text;
    }
function ins_iphone(){
    var text = \"iPhone\";
        document.forms.edit.device.value = text;
    }
function ins_ipod(){
    var text = \"iPod\";
        document.forms.edit.device.value = text;
    }
function ins_ipad(){
    var text = \"iPad\";
        document.forms.edit.device.value = text;
    }
function ins_generic_tablet(){
    var text = \"Generic Tablet\";
        document.forms.edit.device.value = text;
    }
</script>


<form name='edit' method='post'>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"posted\" value=\"TRUE\">
<table width =\"80%\" border=\"1\"><tr style='background:lightblue'><th colspan=\"4\"><h1>Editing record for {$fq['rc_fname']} {$fq['rc_lname']}</h1></th></tr><tr><td>
<tr class='bgalt1'><td><label for='name'>First Name:</label></td><td><input type='text' name='first_name' id=\"name\" value=\"{$fq['rc_fname']}\" /></td>
<td><label for='lname'>Last Name: </label></td><td><input type='text' id='lname' name='last_name' value=\"{$fq['rc_lname']}\" /></td></tr>
<tr class='bgalt3'><td><label for='email'>Email:</label></td><td> <input type='text' id='email' name='email' value=\"{$fq['rc_email']}\" /></td>
<td>Contact Number:</td><td><input type='text' name='contact_no' value=\"{$fq['rc_contactno']}\"/></td></tr>
<tr class='bgalt1'><td><label for='make'>Make: </label></td>
<td><input type='text' id='make' name='make' value=\"{$fq['r_oem']}\" /><br />
<input onclick='ins_apple()' type='button' value='Apple' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_microsoft()' type='button' value='Microsoft' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_hp()' type='button' value='HP' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_dell()' type='button' value='Dell' id='button'><br />
<input onclick='ins_samsung()' type='button' value='Samsung' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_toshiba()' type='button' value='Toshiba' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_asus()' type='button' value='Asus' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_lenovo()' type='button' value='Lenovo' id='button'>
</td><td>device: </td><td><input type='text' id= 'device' name='device' value=\"{$fq['r_device']}\" /><br />
<input onclick='ins_iphone()' type='button' value='iPhone' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_ipod()' type='button' value='iPod' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_ipad()' type='button' value='iPad' id='button'>
<input onclick='ins_generic_tablet()' type='button' value='Generic Tablet' id='button'>
</td></tr>
<tr class='bgalt3'><td>Model: </td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"model\" value=\"{$fq['r_mod']}\"/></td><td>Price: </td><td><input type='text' name='price' value=\"{$fq['r_price']}\"'/></td></tr>
<tr class='bgalt1'><td>Fault</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"fault\" value=\"{$fq['r_reserve']}\" /></td><td>Notes: </td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"notes\" value=\"{$fq['r_notes']}\" onfocus=\"if (this.value=='Add Notes') this.value='';\"/></td></tr>
<tr class='bgalt3'><td>Status: </td><td>"; 
if ($fq['rc_status'] == 1) {
echo'<select name="status" value="options">
<option value="1">Received</option>
<option value="2">Part Waiting</option>
<option value="3">Complete</option>
<option value="4">Beyond Repair</option>
<option value="5">In Progress</option>
</SELECT>';
}
else if ($fq['rc_status'] == 2) {
echo'<select name="status" value="options">
<option value="2">Part Waiting</option>
<option value="1">Received</option>
<option value="3">Complete</option>
<option value="4">Beyond Repair</option>
<option value="5">In Progress</option>
</SELECT>';
}
else if ($fq['rc_status'] == 3) {
echo'<select name="status" value="options">
<option value="3">Complete</option>
<option value="1">Received</option>
<option value="2">Part Waiting</option>

<option value="4">Beyond Repair</option>
<option value="5">In Progress</option>
</SELECT>';
}
else if ($fq['rc_status'] == 4) {
echo'<select name="status" value="options">
<option value="4">Beyond Repair</option>
<option value="1">Received</option>
<option value="2">Part Waiting</option>
<option value="3">Complete</option>
<option value="5">In Progress</option>
</SELECT>';
}
else if ($fq['rc_status'] == 5) {
echo'<select name="status" value="options">
<option value="5">In Progress</option>
<option value="1">Received</option>
<option value="2">Part Waiting</option>
<option value="3">Complete</option>
<option value="4">Beyond Repair</option>
</SELECT>';
}
// error with status code. Use default
else {echo'<select name="status" value="options">
<option value="1">Received</option>
<option value="2">Part Waiting</option>
<option value="3">Complete</option>
<option value="4">Beyond Repair</option>
<option value="5">In Progress</option>
</SELECT>';}

print "</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"pf\" value=\"1\"> Parts Fitted?</td><td colspan=\"1\"><input type='submit' value='Edit Record' /></form></td></tr>
</table></fieldset>";
// now the notes
if (isset($_GET['notedel'])) {
$selnotestodel=$db->query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id={$_GET['notedel']}");
if (mysql_num_rows($selnotestodel)) {
$db->query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE id='{$_GET['notedel']}'");
//print "<div style='background:lightgreen; width:150px'><p><strong>Notes Was Successfully Deleted!</strong></p></div>";
print "<script>alert('Note Deleted Successfully');</script>";
header("location: edit.php?edit={$fq['r_id']}");
}
else 
{
print "<div style='background:#FF9494; width:150px'><p><strong>Sorry the note you are trying to delete doesn't appear to exist...</strong></p></div>";
}
}
if (isset($_POST['n_csumbit'])) {
$nsubject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['n_subj']);
$nnote = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['n_comments']);
$npby = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['n_by']);
$db->query("INSERT INTO notes (linkedtoid, subject, note, postedby) VALUES('{$_GET['edit']}','$nsubject','$nnote','$npby')");
// print "<div style='background:lightgreen; width:150px'><p>Notes Added Successfully.<br /> Added by: {$_POST['n_by']}</p></div>";
print "<script>alert('Note added Successfully');</script>";
header( "Refresh: 0;" );
}
print "<hr /><center><h2>Detailed Notes:</h2></center>
<table width =\"80%\" border=\"1\"><tr style='background:lightblue'><th>Time</th><th>Subject</th><th>Comment</th><th>Made By</th><th>Actions</th></tr>";
if ($db->num_rows($selnotes)) {
while ($nts=$db->fetch_row($selnotes)) {
if ($alternate % 2 == 0){
echo "<tr class='bgalt1'>";
}
else{
echo "<tr class='bgalt3'>";
}
$mysqldate = date('d/m/Y  H:i:s', $nts['time'] );
print "
<td width='10%'>
{$nts['time']}
</td><td width='25$'>
{$nts['subject']}
</td><td width='55%'>
{$nts['note']}
</td><td width='5%'>
{$nts['postedby']}
</td><td width='5%'>
<a href='edit.php?edit={$_GET['edit']}&notedel={$nts['id']}' title='Delete Note'><font color=red><b>X</b></font></a>
</td></tr>
";
$alternate++;
}
}
else {

print "<tr class='bgalt4'><td colspan='5'><center><b>No notes on this repair</b></center></td></tr>";
}
print "
<form name='n_commentspost' method='post'><fieldset>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"n_csumbit\" value=\"1\">
<tr class='bgalt5'><th colspan='5'>Add New Note</th></tr>
<tr class='bgalt5'>
<td>
Subject
</td>
<td>
Comments
</td>
<td>
Made By
</td>
<td colspan='2'>
Submit
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='bgalt1'>
<td>
<input type=\"text\" name=\"n_subj\"/>
</td>
<td>
<textarea name=\"n_comments\"></textarea>
</td>
<td>
<select name=\"n_by\" value=\"options\">
<option value=\"Jon\">Jon</option>
<option value=\"Jason\">Jason</option>
<option value=\"Clodagh\">Clodagh</option>
</select>
</td>
<td colspan='2'>
<input type='submit' value='Add  Note' />
</td>
</tr>
</form></fieldset>
";
print "</table>";

if (isset($_GET['partdel'])) {
$selpartstodel=$db->query("SELECT * FROM usedparts WHERE id={$_GET['partdel']}");
if (mysql_num_rows($selpartstodel)) {
$db->query("DELETE FROM usedparts WHERE id='{$_GET['partdel']}'");
//print "<div style='background:lightgreen; width:150px'><p><strong>Notes Was Successfully Deleted!</strong></p></div>";
print "<script>alert('Part Deleted Successfully');</script>";
header("location: edit.php?edit={$fq['r_id']}");
}
else 
{
print "<div style='background:#FF9494; width:150px'><p><strong>Sorry the part you are trying to delete doesn't appear to exist...</strong></p></div>";
}
}
if (isset($_POST['pa_csumbit'])) {
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_name']);
$linkedto = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['n_comments']);

if (strlen($_POST['item']) > 1) {

            $db->query("INSERT INTO usedparts (binded_to, part_name) VALUES('{$_GET['edit']}','{$_POST['item1']}')");
    }
else {
$db->query("UPDATE repairs SET part1id={$_POST['item1']} WHERE r_id={$_GET['edit']}");
$db->query("UPDATE stock SET commited=commited+1, s_count=s_count-1 WHERE id={$_POST['item1']}");
$db->query("INSERT INTO usedparts (binded_to, part_name) VALUES('{$_GET['edit']}','$name')");
}
// print "<div style='background:lightgreen; width:150px'><p>Notes Added Successfully.<br /> Added by: {$_POST['n_by']}</p></div>";
print "<script>alert('part added Successfully');</script>";
header( "Refresh: 0;" );
}
print "<hr /><center><h2>Parts Used / Needed For This Job:</h2></center>
<table width =\"80%\" border=\"1\"><tr style='background:lightblue'><th>Part Name</th><th>Failed?</th><th>Actions</th></tr>";
if ($db->num_rows($selparts)) {
$partspart1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE id='{$pts['part_name']}'");
$partss=$db->fetch_row("$partspart1");
while ($pts=$db->fetch_row($selparts)) {
if ($alternate % 2 == 0){
echo "<tr class='bgalt1'>";
}
else{
echo "<tr class='bgalt3'>";
}
print "
<td width='60%'>";

print "{$partss['name']}";

print "
</td><td width='20%'>
{$pts['failed']}
</td><td width='20%'>
<a href='edit.php?edit={$_GET['edit']}&partdel={$pts['id']}' title='Delete Note'><font color=red><b>X</b></font></a>
</td></tr>
";
$alternate++;
}
}
else {

print "<tr class='bgalt4'><td colspan='3'><center><b>No parts used for this repair</b></center></td></tr>";
}
print "
<form name='parts_usedpost' method='post'><fieldset>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pa_csumbit\" value=\"1\">
<tr class='bgalt5'><th colspan='5'>Add A Part</th></tr>
<tr class='bgalt5'>
<td>
Part
</td>

<td colspan='2'>
Submit
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='bgalt1'>
<td>
Part Name:<input type=\"text\" name=\"part_name\"/> or Part: ".item_dropdown1($c,'item1')."
</td>
<td colspan='2'>
<input type='submit' value='Add  Part' />
</td>
</tr>
</form></fieldset>
";
print "</table>";


}
print "</div>";
}
?>
```

I don't know how or is there is an alternate way, but what i need is to

take the `$_GET['edit']` use it check my usedparts table to find used parts linked to the id. then needs to display them. Why does that part and only that part not work?

I don't need people to tell me "this should be validated" or this is insecure. its runs on a whitelist, in a local network. security isn't an issue.

EDIT: I've overcome the mysql_fetch_assoc error. Now my problem is i've just realised...

if they use the drop down, part_name is saved as the id.
if they input a new item name, rather than an existing one, it is text.

How can I check if part_name is first an int or text, if its an int, i need to get the name of the stock item from the stock table using that int as the id. then get its name from that row. if its text i just want to output the text as is. how can i check if something is an int, and do something differentially.

Would preg_match be appropriate?

Comment: maybe you should check if mysql_query returned an error. like `die(mysql_error());`

Comment: `security isn't an issue`, the greatest excuse for bad/lazy coding practises I've ever heard.... if you're in the habit of using this excuse, you'll use it where it does matter one day.... and have you never heard of a malcontented employee?

Comment: Im skipping this one, there's a risk of me going blind trying to find what starts and what stops. Try and reduce the code to the actual problem.

Comment: Have you heard of reusable functions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "$_GET['edit']" is valid using in a string `{$_GET['edit']}` this way.

It should be like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from table WHERE name='".$_GET['edit']."'";
```

Try to echo the query at C:\wamp\www\dev\includes\class\class_db_mysql.php on line 67 or before this line.

And see what does it returns. You will see then,which part of your query got wrong data.
If it looks good, try to run the query in phpmyadmin and you will see the error.

Also you can use `echo mysql_error();`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the whole code but you can write this:

```
WHERE r_id='{$_GET['edit']}'"
```

like:

```
WHERE r_id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['edit']) . "'
```

---

I'm fairly certain your query is failing somewhere.

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

And the o-so-required **please don't use mysql_* it is deprecated**